# Going through all Bit Strings with no 11 in it (no consecutive 1s)

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, combinations, computational-mathematics

My question is very simple: How can i (efficiently) go through all Bitstrings which don't contain two consecutive 1s?

So for instance, all Bitstrings of length 3 with no consecutive 1s are: 000, 001, 010, 100, 101.

I need this to be efficient for Bitstrings with length 48.

Cheers!

Edit: Solved it finally: This (unoptimized) code does the job:

```
template< std::size_t N >
bool next( std::bitset<N>& vec )
{
    if( !vec.test(2) && !vec.test(1) )
    {
        vec[1] = true;
        return true;
    }

    for( std::size_t i = 0; i != N - 2; ++i )
        if( vec.test(i) && !vec.test(i+1) && !vec.test(i+2) )
        {
            vec[i] = false;
            vec[i+1] = true;
            for( auto i2 = 1; i2 != i; ++i2 )
                vec[i2] = false;
            return true;
        }

    if( vec.test(N-2) && !vec.test(N-1) )
    {
        for( auto i2 = 1; i2 != N-1; ++i2 )
            vec[i2] = false;

        vec[N-1] = true;

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: How have you tried to tackle this problem? What ideas do you have, and why aren't they working?

Comment: I had numerous ideas. The first one was to use a 2^24 Bitstring and replace all 0s by 00 and all 1s by either 10 or 01. Then i noticed that doesn't work (because i had to replace EVERY 1 by a possibly different Substring). Then maybe a recursive method, with a loop; but then i would have to save the iteration states... eek.

And then i tried just replacing the 1s, and not also the 0s, but that **unfortunately** leads to conflicts when cutting of the 0s.

Comment: Project Euler, eh?

Comment: ****! @fahrbach: How do you know!?!?

Besides, its such a general problem, i wouldn't say it is a sin to ask here.

Comment: @Arcoth, I agree that it is no sin, lol. I read the problem earlier today. The consecutive ones part gave it away. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. :) I already solved the checking part, so i just need to go through all those possible strings - i thought that would be **trivial**, but it absolutely isn't!

Comment: P.S.: I actually thought you figured out that 48 is equal to the ceiled logarithm of 10^10 in base phi.

Comment: @Arcoth, I noticed that $\phi^{48} > 10^{10}$ too. Some other patterns should emerge once you generate your bitmaps!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the sort of thing you are interested, I don't know how to program yet. But you can figure it out "recursively".

For instance, for the problem where you want to find the lists of length $3$ we will need the lists of length $1$ ($1$ and $01$) and the lists of size $2$ ($00$,$01$,$10$) .Now we shall separate the lists of size $3$  into the lists that end in $1$ and the lists that end in $0$.

The lists that end in $1$ are simply the lists of size $1$ with the $01$ added to the very end (so you get $101$ and $001$).

The lists that end in $0$ are simply the lists of size $2$ with the $0$ added to the end so you get $000,010,100$.

If you are interested in counting them you can also use the previous recursive idea. Denote by $f(n)$ the number of lists with no consecutive $1$'s. Then we get $f(n+2)=f(n+1)+f(n)$ This recursion is just a Lucas, or Fibonacci kind of recurrence. In fact $f(n)$ is just $F_{n+2}$(the $n+2$ Fibonacci number).